# How cut a thousands of line T-SQL to small stored procedures or functions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, simplify

I have some problem to reduce the size of my stored procedure, which has more than 2000 lines of code.

Here is a short example (shortly 3 outer XML, 3 inner XML).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spu_Get_Rep_Data
    @IdContrat INT,
    @Annee INT,
    @XML XML OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @XML_Contrat XML;
    EXEC spu_Get_Contrat @IdContrat = @IdContrat, @XML = @XML_Contrat OUTPUT;

    DECLARE @XML_ProdSous_Ev XML;
    EXEC spu_Get_ProdSous_Ev @IdContrat = @IdContrat, @XML = @XML_ProdSous_Ev OUTPUT;

    DECLARE @XML_Ana_Bact XML;
    EXEC spu_Get_Ana_Bact @IdContrat = @IdContrat, @XML = @XML_Ana_Bact OUTPUT;

    SET @XML = (
        SELECT @Annee AS '@Annee',
               @XML_Contrat,
               @XML_ProdSous_Ev,
               @XML_Ana_Bact,
               (SELECT
                    (SELECT IpLibelle AS '@Name',
                        (SELECT
                            (SELECT 'Entry' AS '@Name',
                                    (SELECT 'Stick'    AS '@Type',
                                            '2E5576'   AS '@Color'
                                        FOR XML PATH ('SeriesConfig'), TYPE),
                                    (SELECT p.Year                                             AS '@Name',
                                            ISNULL(CAST(SUM(p.Valeur) AS DECIMAL(18, 8)), '0') AS '@Val'
                                       FROM dbo.Production AS p
                                      WHERE p.Year = @Annee
                                        AND p.IdContrat = @IdContrat
                                        AND p.IpTypeCode = 407
                                        AND p.IpId = e.IpId
                                      GROUP BY p.Annee
                                      ORDER BY p.Annee
                                        FOR XML PATH ('Categorie'), TYPE)
                                FOR XML PATH ('Serie'), TYPE)
                            FOR XML PATH ('VolYear'), TYPE),
                        (SELECT CAST(SUM(Valeur) AS DECIMAL(18, 8)) AS '@Elec'
                           FROM dbo.Production AS p
                          WHERE p.IdContrat = @IdContrat
                            AND p.IpId = e.IpId
                            AND p.IpTypeCode = 101
                            FOR XML PATH ('ElecStep'), TYPE),
                        (SELECT Name  AS '@Val1',
                                Value AS '@Val2'
                           FROM dbo.Production AS p
                          WHERE p.IdContrat = @IdContrat
                            AND p.IpId = e.IpId
                            AND p.IpTypeCode = 653
                            FOR XML PATH ('ReparationStep'), TYPE)
                      FROM dbo.Entite AS e
                     WHERE IdContrat = @IdContrat
                     ORDER BY e.IpLibelle
                       FOR XML PATH ('StepData'), TYPE)
                   FOR XML PATH ('StepsData'), TYPE)
           FOR XML PATH ('Elements')
        )
END
```

It retrieves the data of a "contrat", which may has several types of equipments and each type contains at least one instance, to format XML.

It would be so much better to extract the inner `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH` to stored procedure (which is better in performance than the user-defined function).

Expect result 1 using user-defined function:

```
SET @XML = (
    SELECT @Annee AS '@Annee',
            @XML_Contrat,
            @XML_ProdSous_Ev,
            @XML_Ana_Bact,
            (SELECT
                (SELECT IpLibelle AS '@Name',
                        (EXEC spu_Get_Vol_Year(e.IpId, @IdContrat, @Annee)),
                        (EXEC spu_Get_Elec(e.IpId, @IdContrat)),
                        (EXEC spu_Get_Reparation(e.IpId, @IdContrat))
                    FROM dbo.Entite AS e
                    WHERE IdContrat = @IdContrat
                    ORDER BY e.IpLibelle
                    FOR XML PATH ('StepData'), TYPE)
                FOR XML PATH ('StepsData'), TYPE)
        FOR XML PATH ('Elements')
    )
```

The 3 outer stored procedure works. Since the stored procedure IS NOT allowed using in `SELECT`, the 3 inner stored procedures which need the parameter of *IpId* would not work. Considering that there must be someone who wanted to simplify any large T-SQL to pieces, I took the chance for help.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Consider Table-Valued Functions.  I suspect you will be able to reduce the amount of code and/or touch points.  That said, you MAY sacrifice performance.

Comment: Unless this code is going to be called more than once I don't know that I would split this apart. You will have a performance degradation when you start involving functions and such. It might be small but if you only have this code in one place it isn't going to make things any better. It might be a little easier for the developer but the performance will be slower.